# Dynamically create JS file using ASP.net Handler

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have many clients I want to give them scripts so I want to Create JS file based on their Cusotmer ID.
So I can return and it directly execute on customer side.
Client can be anyone either PHP,Html, ASP.net

**Problem is when i browse this link it give me JS string but on customer side this script is not executing like for testing I put alert this alert is not showing on customer side**

---

Customer

```
<head>
    <script src="http://localhost:12604/JSCreator/Handler.ashx?CustomerID=123" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
```

---

Handler file

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string CustomerId = context.Request["CustomerId"].ToString();
        string jscontent = JSFileWriter.GetJS(CustomerId); // This function will return my custom js string

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
        context.Response.Write(jscontent);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry :) I have updated now question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ContentType` should be `application/javascript`

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string CustomerId = context.Request["CustomerId"].ToString();
    string jscontent = JSFileWriter.GetJS(CustomerId); // This function will return my custom js string

    context.Response.ContentType = "application/javascript";
    context.Response.Write(jscontent);
}
```