# How to use web handlers for PDF creation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, ashx, aspx-user-control

I have pretty less knowledge in web handlers. All I know is web handlers are used for creating some dynamic file creation purpose.

And also I know how to add the Web handlers.

But, I need to use web handlers in my ASP.NET project for PDF creation purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a HTTP handler to serve out your PDFs like this:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

    // Get your file as byte[]
    string filename = "....file name.";
    byte[] data = get your PDF file content here;

    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
    context.Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", ContentType);
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", filename));
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", data.Length.ToString());
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(data);
    context.Response.End(); 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Read [What is an HttpHandler in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391130/what-is-an-httphandler-in-asp-net) and [MSDN: HTTP Handlers and HTTP Modules Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986%28v=vs.140%29.aspx).

You do not *need* a handler to serve files for downloading over HTTP. You can also generate and return a file response in a WebForms page, as well as from ASP.NET MVC and WebAPI.

Depending on the technology you use, check out:

- HTTP handler: [ASP.NET add a httphandler to edit downloaded file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318715/asp-net-add-a-httphandler-to-edit-downloaded-file-name), [Dynamically create JS file using ASP.net Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927185/dynamically-create-js-file-using-asp-net-handler), [MSDN: Serving Dynamic Content with HTTP Handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx)
- WebForms page: [.NET MVC FileResult equivalent in Web Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088962/net-mvc-fileresult-equivalent-in-web-forms)
- ASP.NET MVC: [Download file of any type in Asp.Net MVC using FileResult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult)
- WebAPI: [Returning binary file from controller in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541351/returning-binary-file-from-controller-in-asp-net-web-api)

Of course, any layer on top of a handler (as opposed to running your code from a handler directly) adds additional overhead (though it'll be minimal), where I suspect WebForms to be the heaviest. MVC and WebAPI are run [through the MvcHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchandler%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).