# how do i access server data in separate js file

Tags: javascript, c#

**aspx file**

```
string firsrName="jafer";
```

**myscript.js**

```
GetMyName();

function GetMyName() {

    alert('<%=firstName%>');
}
```

*I am not getting my value*

Comment: Is you JS file generated by some C# code or it is static file?

Comment: You would either have to call the function from the aspx file and pass the variable into the function, or you could create a js handler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927185/dynamically-create-js-file-using-asp-net-handler

Answer (score 1):

The line `alert('<%=firstName%>');` use the Web Form Page syntax. It is actually not possible to get the value like this because this syntax cannot be used in external JS files.

The simpliest (but not cleanest) method is to write the JS method into the layout file or another aspx file.

Read [How to get asp.net client id at external javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845900/how-to-get-asp-net-client-id-at-external-javascript-file)

Answer (score 1):

You could make a global variable in your aspx page and access it in your js using window.objectName